# keyset pagination for specific to jump page

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

is keyset pagination in front end only for next and previous ? because what I have learn about it, I could just use that N keep it for previous and. next

let say this query for page one,
`SELECT * FROM nameTable ORDER BY ASC id LIMIT 10`

and we save the last id on `N`

and then for next  `SELECT * FROM nameTable WHERE id > N ORDER BY ASC id LIMIT 10`

and if for previous just use `WHERE id < N` ?

how about if in Client want to jump to the page 10 or back to 3 pages ??
can u all tell me how to do that and is that possible using `keyset` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get to the previous page, remember the low bound for `id` as well as the high bound.

To scroll 3 pages ahead, use `LIMIT 30 OFFSET 20` instead of `LIMIT 10`. To jump to page X, calculate the difference between X and the current page and multiply that difference with the number of rows per page.

It's all pretty straightforward.

Comment: I still not get it , if I limit 30 then it gonna show 30 items, yes for u pretty straightforward, not for me who is still junior :D

Comment: You have to add `OFFSET 20` if you only want to see the last 10 rows. I thought that was obvious. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: can u tell me again about this `calculate the difference between X and the current page` ? can u give me example

Comment: The difference between X and Y is Y - X. If you are on page 3 and want to skip to page 11, that would be 8.

Comment: and then multiply it of the offset ?

Comment: I don't understand that question. Just sit down and think about it.

Comment: hold on :D, I have 8 pages, and I am on 2 and want to Jump to 5 , then  X would be 3 right? and then 3 multiply 10 (the limit) =`LIMIT 30 OFFESET 20` , is that correct ?

Answer (score 4):

Using keyset pagination **you can not jump to a given page**.

You can just go to **first, last previous and next**.

As explained by Laurenz, **you can still move/skip a number "pages"** from your current stand but I am not really sure what would be the use case for it.

The main objective of keyset pagination is to **avoid the use of the offset/skip - limit for large sets of data**, but if you want to jump to an exact page you must the offset/skip keywords.

Normally **next and prev functionality** using a good search gives good enough user experience :)